# Should I leave cash tips for housekeeping each day of a multi-day stay?

Tags: hotels, tipping

This seems like a bit of a trivial question, but: when staying in a hotel for multiple nights in a row in a location where tipping the housekeeping staff is customary, is it better to leave cash tips for housekeeping every day that the room is kept, or just to leave a single cash tip for the whole stay at checkout?

I would think it likely that different housekeeping crews work different days (especially, e.g., weekends versus weekdays), and it only seems fair to try to ensure that everyone who has worked on the room gets a part of the tips.  But, if it's typical, say, that housekeeping staffs pool the cash tips and distribute them more-or-less evenly, then it's not really worth the trouble of leaving tips daily.

Comment: definitely! the first day, and days after that.  actually i'm not sure i'd bother on the last couple days.  and yeah I'd say always personally - I doubt it is distributed in any way in most locations/hotels.  it's great to tip the cleaning staff!  they both appreciate and deserve it most

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple: **tip daily**, if you can.

If you tip daily, your tips will *definitely* go to all the people who clean your room.

If you tip at the end of your stay, your tip *may or may not* go to all the people who clean your room.

Also, by frontloading your tips, you build up goodwill with the staff, and housekeeping will be happy to do you a favor if you need it.  An extra towel or a few more bottles of water?  No problem!

Comment: Mm, I hadn't thought of the 'building goodwill' aspect, good point. Unless someone with direct behind-the-scenes experience with housekeeping staff tip distribution posts in the next day or so, I anticipate marking this as the answer.