# How to tip housekeeping in hotels if leaving tips daily?

Tags: tipping

I just read a question and answer about tipping housekeeping daily ([Should I leave cash tips for housekeeping each day of a multi-day stay?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48344/should-i-leave-cash-tips-for-housekeeping-each-day-of-a-multi-day-stay)). But how should I physically give them the money? Obviously if I see them I can hand them the money but if I'm out for the day?

I guess I leave cash somewhere obvious, should I leave a note as well? What if it's a non-English speaking country (I'm not sure if you'd be expected to tip there, but maybe you want to). Is there some customary place to leave the tip?

As someone brought up in a generally non-tipping country I often have to work out how to tip, but in general you can just keep an eye on what everyone else does. Not in this case.

Comment: I feel like this is a stupid question, and I could just go find someone and ask, but hopefully an answer here may help someone else who's in the same situation.

Comment: @pnuts -- that's what I've done (I don't generally go as far as the note, but I make it obvious that it's not money I've forgotten). But, the other answer says tip day-by-day, which makes it less easy to be obvious -- I guess the note is the best way. Just wondering if there's some convention.

Comment: Certainly in the Caribbean tipping housekeeping is very much normal.

Comment: If this is a stupid question, then I must be a stupid Aussie. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to leave a tip is in cash and prominently with a note.

It's best to tip once at the end of the stay. It makes it more convenient for you, and for them. Don't worry about not getting the right person - it all averages out, and tips are frequently pooled anyway. However the rest of this answer applies if you are leaving tips daily.

Don't worry about the language issue. Most domestics know enough English to understand "this tip is for you", and they are used to this so just leaving a note is enough, even if they can't read it. The real reason for the note is so that they can prove to management that they didn't steal the money. Again if you leave the tip at the end it's obvious they weren't stealing, as you weren't taking any money left behind.

Comment: _It's best to tip once at the end of the stay._ I've always heard the opposite.  E.g., http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/48346 or http://money.cnn.com/2014/10/16/pf/travel-tipping-guide/index.html  It's certainly more convenient for the guest, but are you sure this is what housekeepers prefer?  I'm skeptical that all of them feel it "averages out" for them.