# How to indicate the tip to cleaners in hotels and motels

Tags: accommodation, tipping

[Tipping overseas guide for Australians: 10 mistakes to avoid](http://www.traveller.com.au/tipping-overseas-guide-for-australians-10-mistakes-to-avoid-gl6fn2) mentions tipping cleaners:

> **Forgetting the cleaners**
>
> It seems ridiculous to you and me, but in the US, and Canada, and many
>   parts of the Middle East, hotel guests are expected to leave money out
>   – the equivalent of a few dollars per day – for the housekeeping team.
>   You'll never see these people, but the cleanliness of your room will
>   certainly increase with the more money you decide to leave.

How do you indicate what money is (and is not) intended as a tip to the cleaners in hotels and motels (in the United States if it needs to be narrowed down to a specific country)?

The question [How to tip housekeeping in hotels if leaving tips daily?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48349/how-to-tip-housekeeping-in-hotels-if-leaving-tips-daily) more or less answers my question, but doesn't address whether cleaning staff may inadvertently interpret money left lying around that wasn't meant as a tip as one.

Comment: @KateGregory well spotted - for some reason I'd seen http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48344/should-i-leave-cash-tips-for-housekeeping-each-day-of-a-multi-day-stay but not that one, even though it was in the "linked" sidebar.

Comment: See discussion in other threads' comments about tipping daily vs at end of stay, especially DJClayworth's; in my opinion, too, tipping at the end of the stay is fine and much simpler (I'd never even heard of tipping daily!)

Comment: Incredibly, I have now started seeing envelopes *marked* for this purpose in chain hotels, in this case, a Marriott.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll refer to [DJClayworth's answer in the other thread](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/48352/36332) (to whom credit):

> The best way to leave a tip is in cash and prominently with a note.
>
> It's best to tip once at the end of the stay. It makes it more
> convenient for you, and for them. Don't worry about not getting the
> right person - it all averages out, and tips are frequently pooled
> anyway. However the rest of this answer applies if you are leaving
> tips daily.

Addressing your additional question about mistaking left cash: during your stay, if you leave any amount of cash during the day, it's highly unlikely housekeeping will interpret the money as a tip unless it's accompanied by a note. At the end of your stay, however, a note is not necessary: if you leave a moderate of cash (on the order of a few dollars per night) in a prominent place, housekeeping will assume it is a tip.